# How can i make a vertical div go horizontal in full screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 divs side by side inside a main div. Lets say- left_div & right_div. When browser is in full screen mode- than left_div is 60% and right_div is 40% in width(as, main_div is 100% width).

Now if i restore the browser window and reduce its width- than the divs get underneath each other but still remains the same percentage as 60% & 40% of the screen.

What i want is that if the browser width gets underneath a certain amount than the divs will get underneath each other and also fillup the whole screen width-ie become full browser width.

How can i do it? Do i need to do it with JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: _"if the browser width gets underneath a certain amount"_ - Try Media Queries. You can specify different styles for different browser widths. Here is a [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) to get you started.

Comment: Could you please make a jsfiddle or post your HTML and CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this once may be help you [here is demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jLo66rvj/)

HTML

```
<div class="left-div">Left</div>
<div class="right-div">Right</div>
```

CSS

```
.left-div{width:60%;height:100px;float:left;background-color:#000;color:#fff} 
.right-div{width:40%;height:100px;float:right;background-color:#333;color:#fff}
@media (max-width: 479px) { 
.left-div, .right-div{float:none;width:100%;} 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Think it will do.

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="left">
        test
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        test2
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.main
{
    width:100%;
}

div.left
{
    width:60%;
    background-color:red;
    float:left;
    height:100px;
}

div.right
{
    width:40%;
    background-color:blue;
    float:left;
    height:100px;
}

@media (max-width: 350px) {
    div.left, div.right
    {
        float:none;
        width:100%;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Your problem has been many people's problem. While you can write your own CSS, but you should consider screens with different DPIs and different devices and different browsers. But Bootstrap allows you to easily manage these situations.

http://getbootstrap.com/

once you include bootstrap in your page, you can have two DIVs like this

http://jsfiddle.net/Gt25L/119/

```
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-8"></div>
```

Also look at the tutorials, and they guide you through how to make responsive websites using bootstrap. you will  not need any JavaScript. Bootstrap is based on CSS only.

This way you have less CSS to maintain and less chance of wrong behaviour in different browsers & devices over time.

Comment: It's quite ease to do this in pure CSS

Comment: That does not answer the question.

Comment: Why downvote? I didn't claim you can't go and set your own CSS. But using a library fixes his problem in minutes without writing any code.

Comment: @Siguza That do answer the question, With bootstrap he can get what he wants easy,

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Look at [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer), namely the part at the bottom with the apples. Your "answer" is like the second and the fourth one combined. It's like someone asking how to make a green background ans you saying "here, read this book on CSS". That is **not** an answer. Your post is about equal to "read about it on Google".

Comment: @Siguza, you are taking it too literally. I he is asking  for direction as 'Should I use jQuery or JavaScript. Not every external link must be voted down.

Comment: @Braim I agree with you, the person who made this question asked if there was a way to do what he wanted and you suggested bootstrap, and i agree with. Bootstrap can easy solve hes needs

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Don't get me wrong, I have no problem with links, nor with third party libraries. But referencing them without explaining how to use them to achieve the desired effect simply does not answer the question. You say: "use Bootstrap". I ask: "use Bootstrap **how**?"